# Embed external native windows app inside electron window

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, electron-builder

Does anyone know if there's a solution / workaround / Library for this in 2020?
We want to embed an Unity3D 3D-window inside our electron.js main window.
Ofc we can just start another .exe as a separate child window. But what about embedding it directly?  We don't have the time to rework our big Unity App to get a WebGL export which is why we want to embed the native App if possible.

I only found this:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10547#issuecomment-344746570

But I have no clue what the OP meant with his workaround.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: This technique uses the windows API to monkey about with these windows by handles. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent which I imagine would be part of this process. You'll need some understanding of win32 native API to pull this off I guess: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/windows.

Comment: Yea that looks like an interesting entry point for the whole thing. I'll dive into this a bit, thanks for the hint man. Did you already use this kind of technique?